# Why is the second jQuery code part / new CSS part I added causing the first jQuery code not to work on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so to improve my skills I decided to build a "Play Market" responcive page.

I built the search bar with the scroll effect (hides when scrolling down - displays when scrolling up). 
(first jQuery part).

and then created the buttons - when clicking the image of the 3 dots it opens a menu (this is my old post:[How to create a button to every list item which opens a menu over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638476/how-to-create-a-button-to-every-list-item-which-opens-a-menu-over-it) ). 
 = Seconde jQuery code part.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/e0byofe2/5/
You cant view the images so this is my older post with printscreens: [How to create a button to every list item which opens a menu over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638476/how-to-create-a-button-to-every-list-item-which-opens-a-menu-over-it) will make it clearer for you.

The first jQuery part is not running on my pc / mmobile browser unlike the code on the JSfiddle that does work very strangely. I dont get any error messages so I don't know where is the problem. I have a feeling that is has to be something with the CSS.

Can someone point out the problem?

This is an update of my code: 
CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 360px)  {

    body{
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .main{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #header-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #689f38;
        height: 62px;
    }

    #header {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgb(10, 29, 90);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgb(10, 29, 90);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px rgb(10, 29, 90);
    }


    .content{
        padding-top: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        /*height: 100%;*/
        background-color: #eeeeee;
    }

    #apps-header{
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-family: arial;
        background-image: url('triangle.png');
        background-position: bottom;
        width: 86px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 10px;
    }

    .line{
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #458b09;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .apps{
        width: 100%;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        padding-top: 10px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .app{
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(145, 145, 145);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(145, 145, 145);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(145, 145, 145);
        background-color: #fafafa;
        padding: 10px 8px;
        margin: 5px 8px;
        display: inline-table; /******/
        position: relative;
        width: 328px;
    }

    .app_icon{
        width: 83px;
        height: 83px;
        float: left;
    }

    .app_info{
        /*border: 1px solid red;*/
        float: left;
        width: 210px;
        height: 81px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .app_name{
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 18px;

    }

    .app_comp{
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 16px;    
        color: #595959;
    }

    .stars img{
        float: left;
        width: 14px; 
        height: 14px;
    }

    .free{
        color: #69a03a;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -25px;
        left: 112px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 43px;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
    }

    .dots{
        height: 25px;
        float: right;   
    }

    .dots_menu{
        display: none;
        width: 202px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 1px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px #000;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px #000;
    }

    .dots_menu.show{
        display: block;
    }

    .dots_menu a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: arial;
    }

}







@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) {

    .content {
        padding-top: 70px;
    }

    #header-wrap {
        height: 55px;
    }

    #header-wrap img {
        width: 53px;
    }

    .app{
        padding: 5px 7px;
        width: 291px;
    }

    .app_icon{
        width: 74px;
        height: 74px;
    }

    .app_info{
        width: 180px;
        height: 74px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .app_name{
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .app_comp{
        font-size: 14px;    
    }   

    .stars img{
        float: left;
        width: 12px; 
        height: 12px;
    }

    .free{
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 107px;
    }

    .dots{
        height: 22px;
    }

    .dots_menu{
        top: 29px;
    }

}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    /************ NAV BAR MENU SLIDE-UP/SLIDE DOWN ************/

    var previousScroll = 0,
        headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();

    $('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
            if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
                $('#header-wrap').slideUp();
            } else {
                $('#header-wrap').slideDown();
            }
        } else {
                $('#header-wrap').slideDown();
        }
        previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });

    /***********************************************************/




    /************ APP INSTALL MENU THING ************/

    $('.dots').click(function(e){
        $('.dots_menu').removeClass('show');
        $(this).next().addClass('show');
        $(document).mouseup(function (e)
        {
            var container = $(".dots_menu");

            if ( ! container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
            {
                $(".dots_menu").removeClass("show");
            }
        });
    });




    /***********************************************************/

});
```

Comment: The images are not working in JSFiddle because they are probably on your pc so the links are not correct. What is not working or what do you want to get working? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: `isn't working` is not a proper problem statement. What's it supposed to do and what part of it isn't doing as expected? What troubleshooting have you tried? What errors are thrown (if any)?

Comment: @charlietfl the first part that hides the search bar stopped working for some strange reason when I added the second juqery part. I added more information to my post.

Comment: @TomSpee you can see some print screens from my older post to make the images more clear for you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638476/how-to-create-a-button-to-every-list-item-which-opens-a-menu-over-it

Comment: You should really make clear what the problem is. The JSFiddle is working fine so the code is correct. It is hard to help you without a proper explanation.

Comment: I quote: "The first jQuery part is not running on my pc / mmobile browser unlike the code on the JSfiddle that does work very strangely. I dont get any error messages so I don't know where is the problem. I have a feeling that is has to be something with the CSS." 
The search bar isn't working on my pc. 
and pasted the updated css code I have because I think it causes the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
on my code I had the body with 100% height. 
I gave it 1000px and it started working again. 
I have no clue why this is happening. 
if anybody knows I will be happy to hear :)

Comment: 100% height didn't work for the 'body' because it's trying to have 100% height from the parent - 'html' and if the parent don't have any height statement then it's won't work. you can set the 'html' to 100% height too because when you set it to 1000px you force the document to be 1000px height no matter what. the whole thing is solved?